# Lottery between teams in array using Java

Tags: java

I am having doubts in implementing a lottery between **4** `teams` in a list and
I have this example below, and it works only that the result is incorrect, the code works, you can click here in the link http://ideone.com/bs9oAZ and test

```
    String[] teams = new String[4];
    teams[0] = "BOSTON";
    teams[1] = "CLEVELAND";
    teams[2] = "SPURS";
    teams[3] = "WARRIORS";

    System.out.println("Number of teams:" + teams.length);

    System.out.print("\n[ ");
    for (String team : teams) {
        System.out.print(team + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");

    for (int i = 0; i < teams.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.format("\n--- Match %02d---\n", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < teams.length; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < teams.length - 1; k++) {
                System.out.println(teams[j] + " - " + teams[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the result is for **1st round**

```
Number of teams: 4
[ BOSTON  CLEVELAND SPURS WARRIORS ]
     
    --- Match 01---
BOSTON - CLEVELAND
BOSTON - SPURS
CLEVELAND - SPURS

--- Match 02---
BOSTON - CLEVELAND
BOSTON - SPURS
CLEVELAND - SPURS

--- Match 03---
BOSTON - CLEVELAND
BOSTON - SPURS
CLEVELAND - SPURS
```

and the correct result for **4** `teams`, it should be for 1st round

```
--- Match 01 ---
BOSTON - CLEVELAND
SPURS  - WARRIORS

--- Match 02 ---
BOSTON    - SPURS
CLEVELAND - WARRIORS

--- Match 03 ---
BOSTON    - WARRIORS
CLEVELAND - SPURS
```

and If I can solve for the **1st round**, I'll try for the **2nd round**.

any suggestion?

Comment: *Hint:* If you want the text printed below the `--- Match NN ---` line to be different, perhaps the code printing that text needs to use the value of `i` for something.

Comment: Hint: the `--- Match NN ---`, its represent  **4 teams** that is **3 games**, like `N-1` like **N** is  the length of teams in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would go about doing it. Only works for even number of teams. Feel free to ask me if you do not understand any part of it.

```
public class Match {
      public static int factorial(int num) {
          int i = 1 ;
          while(num != 1) {
              i = i * num ;
              num-- ;
          }
          return i ;
      }
      public static int search(int[] array) {
          int var ;
          for(var = 0 ; var < array.length ; var++ ) {
             if(array[var] == 0) {
              return var ;
             }
          }
          return -1 ;
      }
      public static void main(String [] args) {
            String[] teams = new String[4];
            teams[0] = "BOSTON";
            teams[1] = "CLEVELAND";
            teams[2] = "SPURS";
            teams[3] = "WARRIORS";
            int [] opp = new int[4] ; // array that determines if a team has got an opposition team
            int comb = (factorial(teams.length)) / (2 * factorial(teams.length - 2)) ; //find no.of possible combinations
            int match = comb / (teams.length/2) ; // find number of matches
            for(int i = 0 ; i < opp.length ; i++) { //clear array
                opp[i] = 0 ;
            }
            System.out.println("Number of teams:" + teams.length);
            System.out.print("[ ");
            for (String team : teams) {
                System.out.print(team + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("]\n");
                for (int j = 1 ; j <= match ; j++) {
                   System.out.format("\n--- Match %02d---\n", j);
                   System.out.println(teams[0] + " - " + teams[j]); //set the first team and its opponent
                   opp[0] = 1 ; // first team has been set 
                   opp[j] = 1 ; // opponent has been set
                   for(int i = 2 ; i <= teams.length/2 ; i++) { //first pair has been set, start from second pair
                       int var1 = search(opp); // look for next team without opponent
                       opp[var1] = 1 ;
                       int var2 = search(opp); // look for next team without opponent
                       opp[var2] = 1 ;
                      System.out.println(teams[var1] + " - " + teams[var2]);
                   }
                   for(int i = 0 ; i < opp.length ; i++) { //clear the array
                        opp[i] = 0 ;
                    }
                }

      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it´s work perfectly, but this solution is only for **4 teams**, this part I understand and if it´s **N**  team?

Comment: This solution works for any even number of teams. Don't forget to change the size of the opp array also.

Comment: ok and thanks again, bu I try for **8 teams** and the result it´s not correct, see this examples here [http://ideone.com/Md0YrH](http://ideone.com/Md0YrH)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do it with arrays, but I'm sure it's much easier with ArrayLists. This is because you are pairing Boston with "X" and then pairing the remaining two, for which the ArrayList class has a lot of convenient methods in hand. Here's the code for you (note that you're still starting with a string array):

```
    String[] teams = {"BOSTON", "CLEVELAND", "SPURS", "WARRIORS"};

    System.out.println("Number of teams:" + teams.length);

    System.out.print("\n[ ");
    for (String team : teams)
        System.out.print(team + " ");
    System.out.println("]");

    ArrayList<String> pair1, pair2;
    for (int i = 1; i < teams.length ; i++) 
    {
        pair1 = new ArrayList<String>(); // initializes this ArrayList
        for(int p = 0; p < teams.length ; p++) // adds the contents of "teams" 
            pair1.add(teams[p]);

        pair2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        pair2.add(pair1.remove(i)); // pair1 has 4 elements,
        pair2.add(pair1.remove(0)); // 2 of which are snatched and put in pair 2.
        pair2.add(0,pair2.remove(1)); //swaps the elements in pair2

        System.out.format("\n--- Match %02d---\n", i);
        System.out.println(pair2.get(0)+"-"+pair2.get(1));
        System.out.println(pair1.get(0)+"-"+pair1.get(1));
    }
```

As you can see the process is very convoluted, and might not even be the best one. But it's the simplest I've come up with so far. If you want one that uses arrays, I can edit this and put that in.

Comment: thanks, but at this stage, it is recommended only to use the arrays, not collections